# Why is blood removed from meat?

Tags: zoology, food, safety

Blood is removed from meat before it is consumed. Below is, for example, how chickens are processed from Wikipedia.

1. Removed from transport cages
2. Hung by the legs on a shackle, mounted on a conveyor chain.
3. Stunned using an electrically charged water bath
4. Killed by cutting the blood vessels in the neck
5. **Bled so that most blood has left the carcass**
6. Scalded to soften the attachment of the feathers
7. Plucked to remove the feathers
8. Head removed
9. Hock cutting to remove the feet
10. Rehung in the evisceration room
11. Gutted or eviscerated to remove the internal organs
12. Washed to **remove blood** and soiling from the carcass
13. Chilled to prevent bacterial spoiling

Why is the blood removed? Does it just simply taste bad? This might be a stupid question but being vegetarian, I may not know.

Comment: we find in the Bible a command not to eat blood and to drain it before eating flesh. This practice may have its roots there.

Comment: Just a guess: blood may contain active immunological modulators and endocrine molecules. But this may be just a general practice because blood [is consumed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_as_food) as food.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about processing of food. Changing the pitch of the question may help.

Answer (score 0):

Blood finds use in many different dishes as well as biotechnological applications. Research-grade BSA (bovine serum albumin) is derived from cow's blood, there are not special facilities, same cows go for steaks and car seats. So part answer is economical: blood can be processed further. Also it is just easier not trying to preserve liquid inside vessel already opened by slitting the throat. It also seems that blood can rot faster than other tissues, maybe, because in dead animal immune responses are deteriorated and every infection in blood will activate.

Comment: Can you add some references, especially for your last sentence?

Comment: I will try to add some reference, but my guess is that bacteria can travel faster in liquid, rather then in tissue through extracellular matrix.

Comment: Right, it's your guess, which is why I asked for references.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it was to do with rotting, but clotting.

Answer (score -1):

I found a [forensic article](http://www.forensicpathologyonline.com/e-book/post-mortem-changes/putrefaction) that states the following:

> Because the protective agencies of the body are absent, the bacteria spread through the blood vessels using the proteins and carbohydrates of the blood as culture media.

I was unable to find anything more on this with my limited searching skill, though I plied it to the best.

There was [an interesting study](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=zkXrVNbaGdOHuASxgoKgCg&url=http://ajph.aphapublications.org/doi/pdf/10.2105/AJPH.14.11.946&ved=0CCQQFjAC&usg=AFQjCNFRYw_gxU6w83Gxg1jZRMTFQ53c4g) on the relation between decompostion of animal meat and the bacterial load though. It was a good read!

Comment: Please cite the reason for downvote, so that I can improve the answer.